How to Scrape YouTube Channels Based on a Keyword List?
I'm looking to scrape YouTube channels based on a predefined keyword list. I want to gather information such as channel names, describtions, subscriber counts.
Are there any Python libraries or API or CLI commands that can help me streamline the process.
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!. Thank you!
I tried youtube-dl but didn't get what I want.

Why not using YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint with q and type=channel?
